# Kafka: can I specify replication quota for a topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

I know in kafka, quotas are used to control client traffic. Recently they proposed something called replication quota which controls replication traffic rate. I've read about them [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-73+Replication+Quotas)

But I still have few more questions regarding replication quota

a) Will replication quotas be valid even when partitions do not move/reassigned? i.e. will replicas be rate-limited during normal circumstances
b) Can I apply replication quota for a particular client-id? If yes, how can I do that?
c) Can I apply replication quota for a particular topic? If yes, how can I do that?